# Why can I not push code on the project I created?

Tags: community-official-site

I have created a project on drupal.org. *The repository for this project is empty* message is shown on the repository page.

> [image: screenshot]

I used to get the Git push instructions on previous days.

I tried to clone the repository using either  the *git@git.drupal.org:project/* or the *https://git.drupalcode.org/project/* link, but I get this error when I run `git push -u origin master`.

> remote:
> remote: You are not allowed to push code to this project.
> remote:
> remote:
> remote:
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

[image]

I also added the SSH key.

> [image: screenshot]

I have also checked to see if my ssh key works or not by running the following command:

```
ssh -T git@git.drupal.org
```

and it is showing welcome message.
Why cannot I push code on the project I created?

Comment: Is the project [Income Expense Tracker](https://www.drupal.org/project/income_expense_tracker)?

Comment: Since you committed code for another project four days ago, something has changed in these days. Did you set Git to use one of the emails you added on https://www.drupal.org/user/3475737/edit/email-addresses?

Comment: Hi @apaderno i did not change the emails. I could not push the code on the gitlab so i trield to push code with other project names but same thing happened. I want to push the codes for this modue https://www.drupal.org/project/expense_tracker

Comment: I have to commit code for a project I maintain. I will be able to see if that happens to me too.

Comment: It would also help to see the full error message, since even wrong permissions on the SSH key file can cause errors. In that case, Git reports a *WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!* error.

Comment: Hi @apaderno my .ssh directory permissions is 700 and the permissions for public key is 644. I have checked the ssh key with the command 'ssh -T git@git.drupal.org' and it is showing welcome message. I have attached the error message when i push the changes on the gitlab https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Lj70.png.

Comment: I was able to commit on the project repository, which means that at least it's not a problem with drupal.org.

Comment: Hi @apaderno thank you for the reply. I'm also able to commit the changes on other previous project repositories and not able to commit the changes if i create new projects.

Comment: [It has been reported on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/infrastructure/issues/3319412). It's probably an issue caused by recent changes they made.

Comment: Thanks @apaderno

Answer (score 1):

I had this error message when pushing to a branch for an issue. My solution was to just go to the project's issue page in drupal.org and click in the button "Get push access"! Now I have push access.